# How can I DROP USER based on a regex in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there a way to perform a DROP at specific prefix users (lets say tenant_* ) of MySQL?

IE :

```
DROP USER 'tenant_george'@'%';
DROP USER 'tenant_john'@'%';
```

etc

Comment: That would require  dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible.

according to the doc to delete multiple users you need to so:

```
DROP USER [IF EXISTS] user [, user] ...
```

in your case, I would rather write a script that generates such line ;-)

(edit: typo)

Comment: This addresses multiple drops at once, but not the desire for "regexp".

Comment: @RickJames sadly regexp does not work to drop users, the few alternatives you have to delete multiple users is to generate your sql/mysql line with a script then capture the output and execute or just copy and paste it. However, you can already write a script to do all the job for you. Other possibility is that you write a store procedure to receive your input, do the select and loop over the results ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create the drop statements using

```
SELECT CONCAT("DROP USER '", user, "'@'", host, "';")
    FROM mysql.user
    WHERE user LIKE 'tenant_%'
```

Adjust the `WHERE` clause as needed (or simply ignore some of the output.)

Then copy/paste the output to perform the DROPs.

(This could be turned into a stored proc, but, assuming it is a one-time task, I suggest including the manual step.  And it gives you a chance to desk-check that you have not accidentally included 'root' or have quoting problems.)